# How do I do this loop in Django template?

Tags: python, django, templates, loops

```
{% for d in mydata %}
    {{ d.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

However, I would like the **first one** to be bolded. How can I use the loop to say...if the d is the first one, then bold it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for.  Looks like:

```
{% for d in mydata %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
        <strong>{{ d.title }}</strong>
    {% else %}
        {{ d.title }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if [`forloop.first`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) is true.